# What are practical applications of AI Planning?

Tags: reference-request, artificial-intelligence, applied-theory, planning

note: any tips toward making this more constructive will be highly appreciated.

I've dealt with ai-related problems, from searching algorithms, to computer vision, to machine learning. However none of which required planning, just algorithms following algorithms.

I'm not sure how effective will it be to implement AI Planning in practical problems, so I'm curious to know if there's a significant effect in doing so. Like at what point does the programmer/designer realize we need to apply AI Planning to solve this.

Comment: pathfinding is an example of planning, but not generally considered artificial intelligence - what trajectory the bot should make through a terrain, what sequence of motions a limb should go through to make contact with a surface. Sometimes planning is used in certain procedures not considered planning (such as searching) to score results by disparity between expectation and reality (some markov models).

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  What do you mean by "a significant effect"?  Also, what does that have to do with at what point the programming realizes we need to apply AI planning?  However, even if you clarify, I'm not sure if the question is suitable -- it looks possibly too broad / dependent on opinion.  Asking for a list of practical applications of AI planning is likely too broad; StackExchange is not ideally suited for list questions..

Answer (score 1):

[*In the following, I am providing links to some events in 2011/2013, but you can find much more looking for previous years*]

By AI Planning I assume that you mean Automated Planning (STRIPS, SAS$^+$ and so on) instead of path-planning and other problems more tightly related to robot navigation. If this is the case, [SPARK](http://icaps13.icaps-conference.org/technical-program/workshop-program/scheduling-and-planning-applications-workshop/) is the right forum to look at.

Other practical applications are often discussed at the main track of the conference [ICAPS](http://icaps13.icaps-conference.org/). A couple of examples:

1. Maria Fox, Derek Long, Daniele Magazzeni: *Automatic Construction of Efficient Multiple Battery Usage Policies*. ICAPS 2011
2. José E. Flórez, Álvaro Torralba Arias de Reyna, Javier García, Carlos Linares López, Angel García Olaya, Daniel Borrajo: *Planning Multi-Modal Transportation Problems*. ICAPS 2011 (admittedly, I am adding here a reference of my own, beg your pardon, I did just because it was easier for me to locate the reference).

Hope this helps,

Comment: The link is dead.